# how to use one core project for a SQL Server 2014 and Azure SQL Database

Tags: sql, database, azure, reference, azure-sql-database

we want to deploy our Software on different editions of SQL Server. So we made a CoreDB Project, and for every edition (Express, Standard, Enterprise) seperate projects. Each references the CoreDB to reduce the amount of objects to define.

Now we want to deploy to Azure DB, but we can not reference the CoreDB from an AzureDB Project.

Any Ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are referring to creating CoreDB and AzureDB as Database projects in SSDT -

Unfortunately SSDT will not allow you to create a Database Reference to another database with a different version. To relate to your earlier example, the following scenario will not be allowed in SSDT:

- CoreDB's target platform is SQL Server 2014
- AzureDB's target platform is Microsoft Azure SQL Database V12

Check a similar question posted here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/af6005a6-5c4d-4c1c-bd8b-209d320ceef7/error-setting-up-db-reference-from-dacpac-versions-dont-match?forum=ssdt

If you've found a way of "reusing" the CoreDB code for different versions since you last posted this, please let me know.

Personally (and based on past experience), I'd use source control to create different branches reflecting the different versions. This allows independent release and code management. It does require more deployment management and synching up, to ensure that the relevant objects will get the same updates.

Julie